Too many requests on AWS Image optimizing functions SST Nextjs
I've deployed my application to AWS following the guide at https://docs.sst.dev/start/nextjs. However, when accessing a specific page with many images, the Next.js <Image /> component returns a 428 error (Too Many Requests).
I switched to using the HTML <img /> tag, but now the images are slow to load and are not being optimized.
This issue occurs only in the production environment, not locally.
